# Both loops think table is always nil, even though it isn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to give users an error when they don't select a row in the table view. Now, the only problem is the searchDisplayController.

This is the IF loop I've came up with for the searchDisplayController. It just doesn't seem to work because every time I select a row, even without using search, the app displays the error.

For example, with the setup available here: http://pastebin.com/q90F3EDa:

1. search for data
2. select a row
3. tap on the row
4. Hit button
5. Gets error

same happens with this setup even when not searching:

1. select a row
2. hit send
3. get error

   ```
   if (self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow == nil) {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                         initWithTitle: @"Select a User"
                         message: @"Please select a user to send a message to."
                         delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   ```

   }

I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this annoying bug.

Thanks,
Arman

Comment: @PhillipMills this didn't really seem to work because the log inside the loop never executed. When I put it outside the loop, i get an error:NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath getCharacters:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc000000000000016' Thanks, Arman

Comment: @PhillipMills I mean the 4 items.

Comment: I gave it in my last comment @PhillipMills

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` is being sent to the `searchResultsTableView` at some point before you check the value of `searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` in the if statements. Make sure that the table view cell is not getting deselected before you have a chance to execute these if statements.

Comment: I looked for anything with this line in my XCProject and it doesn't seem like I ever deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: ! Any other causes, @ndmeiri ?

Comment: But I do assert(index != nil); in the next loop. Index is: NSIndexPath *index = (self.searchDisplayController.active) ? [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
        : [self.usersTable indexPathForSelectedRow];